# how to optimize this popup extension jquery code

Tags: jquery, popup

I have this code below - and am thinking maybe there is a way to make it more concise? I'm not an expert programmer so any help and pointers are appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
        <title></title> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script> 
</head> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            ph      =   $('#popup').height();
            ot      =   $('#launcher').offset().top;
            ats     =   function(){return ot - $(document).scrollTop();}
            abs     =   function(){return ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() ) - ot;}
            popPos  =   function(){
                            var ret = {};
                            if (abs() <= ph) {
                                ret.top = ( ot - ( ph - $('#launcher').height() ) )
                            } 
                            else {
                                ret.top = ot
                            }
                            ret.left = $('#launcher').offset().left;
                            return ret;
                        }
            showPop =   function(){
                            $('#popup')
                                .css(
                                    {
                                        'top'   :   popPos().top    + 'px',
                                        'left'  :   popPos().left   + 'px'
                                    }
                                )
                                .show()
                            ;
                        }

            $('body')
                .click(
                    function(event){
                        if(event.target.id != 'launcher' ){
                            $('#popup')
                                .hide()
                            ;
                        }
                        else {
                            if( $('#popup').is(':visible') ){
                                $('#popup')
                                    .hide()
                                ;
                            }
                            else {
                                showPop();
                            }
                            window.getSelection().empty();
                        }
                    }
                )
            ;
        }); 

</script> 
<style type="text/css"> 
html, body, #container {
    margin          :   0px;
    padding         :   0px;
    border          :   0px;
    width           :   100%;
    height          :   100%;
}
.scroll {
    margin          :   auto;
    overflow-y      :   auto;
    overflow-x      :   hidden;
}
.font {
    size            :   12px;
    line-height     :   14px;
    color           :   #000;
    text-align      :   left;
    font-family     :   'Arial', '_sans';
}
#launcher {
    border          :   1px solid #999;
    width           :   400px;
}
#popup {
    position        :   absolute;
    z-index         :   2;
    width           :   200px;
    height          :   300px;
    border          :   1px solid #900;
    padding         :   0px;
    margin          :   0px;
    background      :   #efefef;
    display         :   none;
}
</style> 
<body> 
dfg<br/><br/><br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>
dfg<br/><br/><br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>
dfg<br/><br/><br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>
dfg<br/><br/><br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>
<div id="launcher" class="x" style="margin-left:76px;">
    launch
</div> 
dfg<br/><br/><br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>
dfg<br/><br/><br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>
dfg<br/><br/><br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>
dfg<br/><br/><br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>
dfg<br/><br/><br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>
dfg<br/><br/><br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>
dfg<br/><br/><br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>
dfg<br/><br/><br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>
dfg<br/><br/><br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>
dfg<br/><br/><br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>
dfg<br/><br/><br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>
dfg<br/><br/><br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>dfg<br/><br/>
 <div id="popup" class="x">
    popup
</div> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Aside from removing tabs and spaces there is nothing verbose about this code.

Comment: @Diodeus Agreed :). tim consider a javascript minifer like [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) that will save you a lot of space. Also, $(document).ready(function... can be simplified to $(function...

Comment: thanks Diodeus and @Andrew. Good feedback, appreciate it

Comment: @Diodeus thanks. in popPos function I thought maybe i can use 'this' instead of my 'ret' object, because i'm not using it anywhere else, but it breaks if i attempt to set this.top, for example. do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Working example of cleaned up code:

http://jsfiddle.net/mLPfd/

Answer (score 0):

My tip is use a semi transparent layer behind the popup. That way you can close the popup when the user clicks on the layer instead of checking every time there is a click in the `body`. Some other clear advantages are:

[image]

See demo here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html

1. You make sure the sure cant click somewhere else while the popup is active
2. It looks good and centers the user attention in the popup

Also note that this question maybe more suited to: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: But i wasn't asking about how to structure a popup widget. Your widget is totally different from mine.

Comment: @tim you question is "how to optimize this popup extension jquery code" and my advice was that you used a layer behind the popup. How does this optimizes your plug in? well if you used a layer that way you know when someone clicks outside the popup by just listening to the mouse click on the layer rather that having to listing to any clcik in the body which is what you are currently doing. This would also drastically reduce lines of code and have much more sense. The link was just so you noticed how the layer worked.